# Intern JS - asynchronous hook before test definition?

Tags: javascript, testing, asynchronous, intern

I'd like to do an asynchronous action before defining my tests. For example, load a `jsdom` environment.
When doing this, intern runs 0 tests. 
What would be the right way to do this?
I cant do this in the config itself, as the config needs to be loaded in order for intern to find `jsdom`.

my intern config loads the following file:

```
define( [
        "intern/dojo/node!jsdom"
    ], function(
        jsdom
    )
{
    "use strict";

    var body = "";
    var scripts = [];

    jsdom.env( body, scripts, function( err, window )
    {
        define( [
            "./test_MyRenderer",
            ], function()
        {
        } );
    } );
} );
```

test_Renderer, defines the actual tests

```
define( [
        "intern!bdd",
        "intern/chai!expect",

        "src/Renderer"
    ], function(
        bdd,
        expect,

        Renderer
    )
{
"use strict";

bdd.describe( "Renderer", function()
{
    it( ...
    it( ...
} );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @jason0x43, I found out about `config.setup`. Unfortunately, this is executed after the suites are loaded, which means I still have to load the sources in a before hook. For completeness, this is my solution. 
in the intern config:

```
cfg.setup = function()
{
    return new Promise( function( resolve, reject )
    {
        require( [
                "intern/dojo/node!jsdom"
            ], function(
                jsdom
            )
        {
            var body = "";
            var scripts = [];

            jsdom.env( body, scripts, function( err, window )
            {
                global.document = window.document;
                resolve();
            } );
        } );
    } );
};
```

my test suite:

```
define( [
        "intern!bdd",
        "intern/chai!expect",

    ], function(
        bdd,
        expect,
    )
{
"use strict";

bdd.describe( "Renderer", function()
{
    var RendererClass;

    bdd.beforeEach( function()
    {
        return new Promise( function( resolve )
        {
            require( [ "src/Renderer" ], function( Renderer )
            {
                RendererClass = Renderer;
                resolve();
            } );
         } );
    } );

    it( ...  var subject = new Renderer(); ...
    it( ...
} );
```

Answer (score 3):

The Intern config file can have `setup` and `teardown` methods, just like a test suite. These will be run before testing begins and after it finishes. This is an official, but as yet poorly documented feature.

Comment: Ah, that's very useful. I'm assuming I can deal with my asynchronicity by making `setup` return a promise, just like the hooks from suite?

Comment: Yes, that'll do it.

Comment: Thanks, accepting this as the answer. An ideal solution would involve something less global, so I can keep it closer to the specific test(s).

Comment: Ah. Well, you could use the `setup` and `teardown` methods in a test suite. Those are called before and after the tests in that suite.

Comment: Problem there is that I  would need to be able to define the hook before I load my sources and specify the tests. And if I do that, intern won't execute the tests.

Comment: Why would you need to load the hook before your tests are specified?

Comment: In this specific case, as soon as I require the module under test, the module trows `document is not defined`, because I'm running in node. (I'm aware of the smell ;) )

Comment: Ah, ok. Given that, yes, `config.setup` is probably the easiest option, or you could require the module(s) under test in the suite's `setup` method, after the jsdom module had been loaded.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121328/discussion-between-sirlenz0rlot-and-jason0x43).